# Dynamically create schema in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring boot application that uses JPA with Hibernate. It already connect to a primary data source for all transactions.

Now the task in hand is that I need to dynamically create Database Schema in a different database. For instance,

For project 1, create schema 1 in Database X
For project 2, create schema 2 in Database X

Later, these databases will be used by others externally. I am looking for the best way to get this done.

Comment: You can use `gradle` with `flyway` then create a task in order to create a schema for database.

Comment: You can also try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47091739/1092818)

Comment: you question is a bit abstract, you want to connect to 2 datasources?
When you say project 1 and 2 are those applications or tables in primary source?

Answer (score 0):

In case of defining multiple datasources in spring boot project, you have to declare associated beans in your configuration. With spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create it will automatically create the schema in right database [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275448/multiple-data-source-and-schema-creation-in-spring-boot)